# Combine online .csv files into data frame in R

Tags: r, url, for-loop, download, dataframe

I need to download 300+ .csv files available online and combine them into a dataframe in **R**. They all have the same column names but vary in length (number of rows).

```
l<-c(1441,1447,1577)
s1<-"https://coraltraits.org/species/"
s2<-".csv"

for (i in l){   
    n<-paste(s1,i,s2, sep="") #creates download url for i
    x <- read.csv( curl(n) ) #reads download url for i
    #need to sucessively combine each of the 3 dataframes into one 
}
```

Comment: `read.csv` accepts urls : `tmp <- do.call('rbind', tmp1 <- Vectorize(read.csv, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)(paste0(s1, l, s2)))` where `tmp1` will have your list of data frames and `tmp` will be them combined

Answer (score 5):

Like @RohitDas said, continuously appending a data frame is very inefficient and will be slow. Just download each of the csv files as an entry in a list, and then bind all the rows after collecting all the data in the list.

```
l <- c(1441,1447,1577)
s1 <- "https://coraltraits.org/species/"
s2 <- ".csv"

# Initialize a list
x <- list()

# Loop through l and download the table as an element in the list    
for(i in l) {   
    n <- paste(s1, i, s2, sep = "") # Creates download url for i
    # Download the table as the i'th entry in the list, x
    x[[i]] <- read.csv( curl(n) ) # reads download url for i
}

# Combine the list of data frames into one data frame
x <- do.call("rbind", x)
```

Just a warning: all the data frames in `x` must have the same columns to do this. If one of the entries in `x` has a different number of columns, or differently named columns, the `rbind` will fail.

More efficient row binding functions (with some extras, such as column filling) exist in several different packages. Take a look at some of these solutions for binding rows:

- `plyr::rbind.fill()`
- `dplyr::bind_rows()`
- `data.table::rbindlist()`

Answer (score 1):

If they have the same columns then its just a matter of appending the rows. A simple (but not memory efficient) approach is using rbind in a loop

```
l<-c(1441,1447,1577)
s1<-"https://coraltraits.org/species/"
s2<-".csv"

data <- NULL
for (i in l){   
    n<-paste(s1,i,s2, sep="") #creates download url for i
    x <- read.csv( curl(n) ) #reads download url for i
    #need to sucessively combine each of the 3 dataframes into one 
    data <- rbind(data,x)
}
```

A more efficient way would be to build a list and then combine them into a single data frame at the end, but I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: "but I will leave that as an exercise for you." lol. Show it in your answer, instead.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Rohit. Your solution works but yes as you say it is a bit memory inefficient. I have 370 online csv files each about 30 x 200) to combine. So might need to consider the list alternative.